# Ember view doesn't update after store.unloadAll if single item is in model

Tags: ember.js, view, model, ember-data

All records are unloaded from the store, but it doesn't change in view when single item is shown. If multiple items are shown, everything updates correctly.

**live example:** http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mojase/2/edit?html,js,output

singleItem should also disappear when all items are unloaded, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is working as intended.

`find` without a parameter is a live collection of all of the records in the store, and as such, when a record is removed from the store, it's removed from that collection.

`find` with a parameter defined is a single record (unless you're finding by query, but in this case you aren't), and Ember Data doesn't have a mechanism for retracting your reference to an object.  Likewise, if you were to take the results from the `find` call without the parameter, and copy it into an array, then remove all of the items from the store, that array wouldn't be modified.

Comment: So how do I make it update ? By using filter instead of find ?

Context:
I want to use this for authentication. When application loads, I find current user as assign it as a model for application, and when user logs out, I send request to logout and also unload user model.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe a `RSVP.hash` is what you need:

> An important note: RSVP.hash is intended for plain JavaScript objects
>   that are just a set of keys and values. RSVP.hash will NOT preserve
>   prototype chains.
>   http://emberjs.com/api/classes/RSVP.html#method_hash

Your model should contain an `array of objects` or a `single object`, not both. Otherwise, you have unnecessary duplication in the model itself.

You can compare your `route model` to amazon: *'I do not know why you need all this stuff, but you ordered it. I promise you I will deliver them. So wait until the package arrives. Then you can filter, order, modify, .. your stuff however you like!'*.

Your page logic goes into your `ApplicationController`, it's like your home, where your amazon stuff arrives and you can use it however you like.

So in code:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find("post");
  }
});

App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
 singlePost: function() {
   return this.get('model').findBy('id', '1');
 }.property('model.@each.id'),
  actions: {
    unload: function(){
      this.store.unloadAll("post");
    }
  }
});
```

**Note** that I use an `ArrayController` because I am returning an array of records. Use a `Controller` when only 1 record is returned via your model.

Working jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zasorasido/1/edit?html,js,output